# How to duplicate every word in the first line of a file

Tags: dataframe, awk, sed, duplicates

How can I duplicate every word in the header of a file?
I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
ID    sample1    sample2    ...
123    1 0     1 2    ...
...
```

I want to duplicate every column header in the file such that after splitting the data at the space, each of them will have a header.

Desired output:

```
ID    sample1    sample1    sample2   sample2    ...
123    1    0    1    2    ...
...
```

I tried to use sed:

```
sed -e '1s/*./& &/g' file.in
```

but it only append the duplicated content at the end of the line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some like this:

```
awk 'NR==1 {printf "%s ",$1;for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s %s ", $i,$i;print "";next}1' file
ID sample1 sample1 sample2 sample2 ... ...
123    1 0     1 2    ...
...
```

In line #1, it duplicates every word, except the first.

Using `TAB` as separator

```
awk 'NR==1 {printf "%s\t",$1;for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s\t%s\t", $i,$i;print "";next} {$1=$1} 1' OFS="\t" file
ID      sample1 sample1 sample2 sample2 ...     ...
123     1       0       1       2       ...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `awk` is to simply use string concatenation to duplicate each field from 2 on. For example using a 3-space separator (and your input file with the ellipses in place), you could do:

```
$ awk 'FNR == 1 { for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) $i = "   " $i "  " $i }1' file
ID    sample1  sample1    sample2  sample2    ...  ...
123    1 0     1 2    ...
...
```

The essential part of the expression is simply setting `$i = "   " $i "  " $i` to duplicate the field.

Using `sed` with extended regular expressions, you could do:

```
sed -r '1 s/\s+\w+/& &/g' file
ID    sample1     sample1    sample2     sample2    ...
123    1 0     1 2    ...
...
```

Where limiting the line `1` you match any one or more separator characters `\s+` followed by one or more word characters `\w+` and replace it with what is matched -- twice, `& &`.

You can do the same thing a bit more crudely with basic regular expressions using:

```
sed '1 s/[ \t][ \t]*[^ \t][^ \t]*/& &/g' file
```

Where you match one or more spaces or tabs followed by one or more not-spaces or not-tabs. (same output, but it also duplicates the ellipses in the first line)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\s{2,}/\t/g;1h;1d;2{H;s/\t/& /g;G;s/^\S+([^\n]*\n)(\S+)/\2\1/;:a;s/\t \S+([^\n]*\n(\t\S+))/\2\t\1/;s/\t(\t[^\n]*\n)\t\S+/\1/;ta;s/\t\n\t\S+//};y/ /\t/' file
```

Replace all 2 or more consecutive spaces by tabs. Copy the header to the hold space and delete it. Append the second line to the hold space and prepend a space following each tab in the second line. Append the first and second lines to the second line. The first line in the pattern space is used as a template for the headings. The first column is special (ID) and is copied non-iteratively. All other heading are replaced iteratively until there no further headings. The last tab of the first line and the remainder of the second line (last column of the headings) is removed. All subsequent spaces are replaced by tabs.

N.B. All columns will be tab delimited, if space delimited is preferred, replace the last command by `y/\t/ /`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you actually meant `'1s/.*/& &/g'` rather than `'1s/*./& &/g'`?

In that case, remember that `*` is a *greedy* quantifier, so will match the whole line.  You want to match each *word* on the line:

```
sed -e '1s/\w\+/& &/g'
```

Looking at the example, it seems that we don't want the first word (`ID`) to be doubled like the rest - only the words with preceding whitespace:

```
sed -e '1s/ \+\w\+/&&/g'
```

Output:

```
ID    sample1    sample1    sample2    sample2    ...
123    1 0     1 2    ...
```